# If $g\lt f$, then $\varphi(t)\lt \psi(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this question:

> In the rectangle $P=\{(t,x);|t-t_0|\lt a,|x-x_0|\lt b\}\subset \mathbb
>  R^2$, let $f,g$ be two continuous functions and locally Lipschitz. If
>   $g\lt f$ in P, then for $\varphi$ and $\psi$ solutions of,
>   respectively,
>
> $x'=g(t,x),x(t_0)=x_0$ and $x'=f(t,x)$, $x(t_0)=x_0$
>
> defined in $0\le t\le c$.
>
> Prove that $\varphi(t)\le \psi(t)$ for every $t_0\lt t\le c$.

I've already tried to use Picard Theorem and Gronwall's inequality without success, maybe we have to use some real analysis tricks, I don't know. I really need a hint to begin to solve this question which seems really hard to me due my lack of experience in this subject.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose instead that $\varphi>\psi$ somewhere, i.e. take $T\in(0,c]$ with $\varphi(T)>\psi(T).$ Let $t_\ast$ be the largest time less than $T$ at which $\varphi\leq\psi$, so that in particular $\varphi(t_\ast)=\psi(t_\ast).$ Now given what we know about $g$ and $f$, $\varphi'(t_\ast)<\psi'(t_\ast)$ which implies that immediately to the right of $t_\ast$ we have $\varphi<\psi$. But now $\varphi(T)>\psi(T)$ and $\varphi(t_\ast+\varepsilon)<\psi(t_\ast+\varepsilon)$ which implies existence of $t^\ast\in(t_\ast+\varepsilon,T)$ where $\varphi(t^\ast)=\psi(t^\ast).$ This contradicts maximality of $t_\ast.$

Comment: Why $\varphi'(t_\ast)<\psi'(t_\ast)$ implies that immediately to the right of $t_\ast$ we have $\varphi<\psi$? I don't remember the real analysis argument for this.

Comment: Try showing that if there's a sequence of points coming from the right and converging to $t_\ast$ where $\varphi\geq\psi$ then $\varphi'(t_\ast)\geq\psi'(t_\ast).$ Use continuity of $\varphi'$ and $\psi'$